# Change the average grouped calculation for a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

quick question because I'm getting crazy on this issue.
I have a table where I save a lot of analytics data, and I have to put this data on a table.

Every record has this structure:

```
id: 1,
user_id: 4,
store_id: 490,
company_id: 1,
completed_courses_percentage: 87
```

At this moment I'm grouping the user by company and then I use the average method to create a table with the average completed course percentage grouped by company.

`UserActivity.group(:company_id).average(:completed_courses_percentage)`

If I have three person for a company and the averages are 0, 50 and 100 the total average now is 50%.

By the way I need to change the way I calculate this average: I must calculate the average of people that belong to a company with a completed_courses_percentage > 70.

I try to use

```
UserActivity.group(:company_id).having("completed_courses_percentage > 70")
```

but the result is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
UserActivity.where("completed_courses_percentage > 70").group(:company_id).average(:completed_courses_percentage)
```

P.S: Not tried this.